# JavaFX 8: Reusing of FXML

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Given I have an FXML which represents a form to create a data record. If I use this FXML only for a `CreateRecordController` I could bind the controller directly in the FXML and use the `fx:id`s to bind the controls to this controller.

But what would I do if I want to reuse this FXML for an `EditRecordController` as well? I cannot bind two controllers in the FXML. Is there a way to do this binding in the FXML loader??

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the controller instance to `FXMLLoader` before loading the fxml. This requires the `fx:controller` attribute to be absent from the fxml file:

```
Object controller = ... // create an instance of the desired controller class here

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/some/path/myfxml.fxml"));
loader.setController(controller);

Node root = loader.load();
```

Note: *Binding is the wrong term here, since you do not assign the controller to any javafx property.*